# How do I pass head(xs) as one arguement into another function?

Tags: haskell, arguments

So i have this function

```
intCMP :: Int -> Int -> Ordering
intCMP a b | a == b =EQ
           | a < b = LT
           | otherwise = GT
```

and this list defined

```
xs = [1,2,3]
```

I'm trying to find information about the list but I'm having troouble passing elements into intCMP

This is what I'm trying to do

```
intCMP head(xs) 1
```

But this give me and error saying it has too many arguements.

```
<interactive>:2:9: error:
       • Couldn't match expected type ‘Int’ with actual type ‘Integer’
       • In the first argument of ‘intCMP’, namely ‘(head xs)’
         In the expression: intCMP (head xs) 1
         In an equation for ‘it’: it = intCMP (head xs) 1
```

Comment: Could you please share the exact output of running your program, and a unified view of the source code?

Comment: That's all I have as the source code, just the function and the list defined. but i'll show you the error.

Comment: There is (or should be) a difference between `intCMP (head xs) 1` and `intCMP head(xs) 1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is not about having too many arguments, it's about the type of your list elements being `Integer` instead of the expected `Int`.

You have two choices here:

First: Make your function more general by allowing all `Ord` (Orderable) types to be accepted (note that this function is available in Prelude as `compare`)

```
intCMP :: (Ord a) => a -> a -> Ordering
intCMP a b | a == b =EQ
           | a < b = LT
           | otherwise = GT
```

Second, cast your list element's type to the one required using `fromIntegral`:

```
intCMP (fromIntegral $ head intxs) 1
```

Answer (score 4):

In Haskell, functions are called by typing the name of the function, followed by each argument. The arguments are separated by space.

In other languages, particularly the descendants of C, you call methods by passing arguments in brackets, but not in Haskell. The brackets don't indicate a function call, they're used entirely to modify the normal operator precedence.

It's like in basic arithmetic, where you have a normal order of operator precedence. For example, `1 + 2 * 3` is the same as `1 + (2 * 3)`, so you normally don't write the latter. If, however, you wish to evaluate the addition before the multiplication, you use brackets to indicate a deviation from the norm: `(1 + 2) * 3`.

It's the same in Haskell. You need to pass two values to `intCMP`, which you can do like this:

```
Prelude> intCMP (head xs) (head (tail xs))
LT
```

Basically, you only need to move the brackets around a bit.

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the parentheses differently

```
 intCMP (head xs) (head $ tail xs)
```

Because in haskell function application is just white space.

Your expression is parsed as `intCMP head xs head (tail xs)` which is not what you intended.